# Add django url template tags to pandas html table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, pandas

In my django-view I use pandas to create a pivot table which is then handed via context to the template. This works just fine. I want the headers of the columns to be links triggering new views. So I wrote a simple jQuery script to do this. But I run into problems as soon as I want to pass a kwarg with the url template tag..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('thead th').each(function(){
      $(this).html('<a href="{% url "cat_view" cat="' + $(this).html() +'" %}">'+ $(this).html() +'</a>');
    });
  });
```

I get the following error:

> Reverse for 'cat_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'cat': "' + $(this).html() +'"}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['category/(?P[\w-]+)/$']

my url entry looks like this:

```
    url(r'category/(?P<cat>[\w-]+)/$', categoryView, name='cat_view'),
```

Am I making an error with the syntax or is it a general problem with my approach? The error message suggests, that django interprets what I write in the jQuery script instead of what the jQuery is supposed to pass over to django.. but I don't know how to avoid this..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that Django renders the URLs before the JQuery code is interpreted. I would use a GET parameter instead :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('thead th').each(function(){
      var html = $(this).html();
      var url = "{% url "cat_view" %}?cat=" + html;
      $(this).html('<a href="' + url + '">'+ html +'</a>');
    });
});
```